# Searching by Client ID not working

Tags: java

When I run this program and enter in the Client information, then decide to search by the clientID it will always return client not found.

This is the case in which the search option is selected:

```
case 2: 
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the client ID to search for: ");
    while(checkSearchClientID(input) == false)
    {   
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid! Only 9 digits allowed. Re-enter search ID: ");
    }
    searchClient = input;
    searchClient();
    if(foundAt < 0)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Client not found!");
    }
    else
    {
        OptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Found at: " + foundAt);
        client[foundAt].dispClient();
    }
    break;
```

and this is the search method

```
public static void searchClient()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < ccount)
    {
        if(searchClient.equals(client[i].clientID))
        {
            foundAt = i;
        }//end if
        i++;        
    }//end while
    foundAt = -1;
}//end searchClient
```

This is where the client ID is entered

```
void getClient()
{
    String input = new String (" ");
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter client ID: ");
        while(checkClientID(input) == false)
        {   
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid! Only 9 digits allowed. Re-enter client ID: ");
        }//end while
    clientID = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

No matter what result occurs, the `public static void searchClient()` method always sets foundAt to -1.

```
public static void searchClient() {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < ccount)
    {
        if(searchClient.equals(client[i].clientID))
        {
            foundAt = i;
        }//end if
        i++;        
    }//end while
    foundAt = -1;  // this always occurs, no matter the result from the while block
}
```

One solution: set foundAt to -1 at the **beginning** of the method, not the end.

```
public static void searchClient() {
    foundAt = -1; // ***** here
    int i = 0;
    while (i < ccount)
    {
        if(searchClient.equals(client[i].clientID))
        {
            foundAt = i;
        }//end if
        i++;        
    }//end while
    // foundAt = -1;  // **** not here
}
```

Also, consider having this method **return** the foundAt int so that it returns a result rather than updates via side-effect.

Comment: Alright I removed foundAt = -1;... 
But now when I add multiple clients it will always return foundAt to 0 even if I add two different clients and search by each one

Comment: @MichaelAndrews: are you adding `foundAt = -1;` to the beginning of the method?

Comment: Yes. I added foundAt in the beginning of the method and now it cannot find any client

Comment: It's always coming up with Client not found now.

Comment: @MichaelAndrews: time to debug your program, to inspect your variables while the program is running, to see what they're doing and to see which one is misbehaving.